# React-Redux call to firebase isnt showing data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

Im running into a problem with my redux to firebase connection i believe.
Trying to grab all jobs from users in firebase.

Have my store setup, action and reducer, not really sure where i am going wrong here so i must be overlooking something, nothing is showing up in console and i put a console.log call on my action and nothing shows still.

my action :

```
// Grab all Jobs
export const getJobs = (jobs) => ({
    type: 'GET_JOBS',
    jobs
});

export const startGetJobs = () => {
    return(dispatch, getState) => {
        const uid = getState().auth.uid;
        return database.ref(`users/${uid}/jobs`)
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            const jobs =[];
            console.log(jobs);

            //Parse the data using snapshot
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                jobs.push({
                    id: childSnapshot.key,
                    ...childSnapshot.val()
                });
            });
            dispatch(getJobs(jobs));
        });
    };

};
```

my reducer file :

```
const jobReducerDefaultState = [];

export default (state= jobReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_JOB':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.job
            ];
        case 'REMOVE_JOB':
            return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id);
        case 'EDIT_JOB':
            return state.map((job) => {
                if(job.id === action.id) {
                    return {
                        ...job,
                        ...action.updates
                    };
                } else {
                    return job;
                }
            });
        case 'GET_JOBS':
            return action.jobs;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

my redux store file :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import jobsReducer from '../reducers/jobs';
import filtersReducer from '../reducers/filters';
import authReducer from '../reducers/auth';


const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default () => {
    const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        jobs: jobsReducer,
        filters: filtersReducer,
        auth: authReducer
    }),
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    );
    return store;
};
```

And trying to call that with this component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import JobDataItem from './JobDataItem';
import { startGetJobs } from '../actions/jobs';

class JobData extends React.Component {

    ComponentDidMount() {
        this.props.startGetJobs();
    }
    render() {


    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.jobs.map((job) => {
                return <JobDataItem key={job.id} company={job.company}/>
            })}
        </div>
    );
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        startGetJobs: (jobs) => dispatch(startGetJobs(jobs))
    }
}
export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(JobData);
```

which passes that data to the jobDataItem component to render to screen below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const JobDataItem = ({ id, company}) => (
    <div>
        <Link to={`/edit/${id}`}>
            <h3>{company}</h3>
        </Link>
    </div>
);

export default JobDataItem;
```

my firebase db formats like:

```
users/
      user-uid/
               jobs/
                    job-uid/
                            company:"Company Name",
                            jobTitle:"jobTitle:,
                            And so on...
```

Expected output is "Company Name" but nothing shows up at all. i try to just call `props.jobs.length` and it shows up as 0 as well.

**EDITED**
1. “Called startGetJobs in componentDidMount(),
2. “Changed `props.jobs.map((job)...` to `this.props.jobs.map((job)...`

I now get props is undefined error in console and nothing still appears on screen.

Comment: Where do you call `startGetJobs `

Comment: Sorry @blaz i just edited the question to show ```JobData``` component calling ```startGetJobs```

Comment: @r.marsh in your mapDispatchToProps() your define startGetJobs: (jobs) => dispatch(startGetJobs(jobs)) with an argument of jobs, yet in your componentDidMount() and action-creator, jobs is not an argument to call this action-creator. Try removing the argument in mapDispatchToProps and see what occurs. Also ComponentDidMount() should be lowercase, mind casesfor life-cycle methods.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo i changed what you said and it made no difference. i am now getting the error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined
    at JobData.render (JobData.js:20)``` which is where i use ```{props.jobs.map((job) => {
                return <JobDataItem key={job.id} company={job.company}/>
            })}```. so its not even picking up the dispatch as props.

Comment: You make a trivial mistake: it should be `this.props.jobs.map((job)`, not `props.jobs.map((job)`. Please fix it.

Comment: Changed that and still nothing shows, console is throwing error props is not defined. From that exact line.

Comment: Where is your `mapStateToProps`? You need that to get data from redux state.